# Simultaneously replacing all values of a dictionary to zero python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a very large dictionary, maybe about `10,000 keys/values` and I want to simultaneously change all values to `0`. I am aware that I can loop through and set all the values to `0` but it take forever. Is there anyway that I can *simultaneously* set **all** values to `0`?

Looping method, very slow:

```
# example dictionary
a = {'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'b': 1, 'e': 1, 'd': 1, 'g': 1, 'f': 1, 'i': 1, 'h': 1, 'k': 1,
 'j': 1, 'm': 1, 'l': 1, 'o': 1, 'n': 1, 'q': 1, 'p': 1, 's': 1, 'r': 1, 'u': 1,
 't': 1, 'w': 1, 'v': 1, 'y': 1, 'x': 1, 'z': 1}
for key, value in a.items():
    a[key] = 0
```

Output:

```
{'a': 0, 'c': 0, 'b': 0, 'e': 0, 'd': 0, 'g': 0, 'f': 0, 'i': 0, 'h': 0, 'k': 0,
 'j': 0, 'm': 0, 'l': 0, 'o': 0, 'n': 0, 'q': 0, 'p': 0, 's': 0, 'r': 0, 'u': 0,
 't': 0, 'w': 0, 'v': 0, 'y': 0, 'x': 0, 'z': 0}
```

Comment: Have you profiled your code and found this to be the limiting factor?  A dictionary with 10k items is not very large.

Comment: Its not so much the size it is how many times that I am going to be looping through the dictionaries. I have it programmed to loop through almost every second and additionally, I have not one but multiple dictionaries.

Comment: You could simultaneously set all values to 0 if all values would be in a continuous memory block. I don't think you can do this with the builtin dict... unless you create your create your own dict implementing data structure in C.

Comment: @loanAlexandruCucu Thanks for the advice! I think I might just do that.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? Maybe there's a better approach.

Comment: The best method would be to make a copy of the empty dictionary before you start putting stuff into it.

Comment: Depending on how you use the dict, this might be a constant-time solution: `a = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 0)`

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You want `dict.fromkeys()`:

```
a = dict.fromkeys(a, 0)
```

Comment: is that any faster than looping?  and I believe it'll take twice the memory while running, as it's creating a separate copy, correct?

Comment: Surprisingly, looping is faster, your method, `10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0226 usec per loop`, looping `10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0224 usec per loop`

Comment: @enginefree thanks for profiling; I would imagine the two should be similar since both your original loop and fromkeys likely use iterators.  I think kreativitea's idea to store an empty copy makes the most sense.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks @akaRem for his comment :)

```
a = dict.fromkeys( a.iterkeys(), 0 )
```

Comment: since you do not need copy of all keys, it will be better to use `iterkeys()`

Comment: right now the 'iterkeys()' method is known as 'keys()' - see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html
(added just for clarification, because this topic  - although quite old -  seems to be alive)

Answer (score 3):

Be warned, if the order of your keys matter the solution may not be suitable as it seems to reorder.

To stop this from happening use list comprehension:

```
aDictionary =  { x:0 for x in aDictionary}
```

**Note:** It's only 2.7.x and 2.x exclusive

Comment: @NoahGary I think the OP meant "exclusive of Python 2.x", so it works with Python 3.x

Answer (score 0):

To expand on [@Daniel Roseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman) answer `a=a.fromkeys(d,0)` is functionaly the same and a bit faster. Also if you plan to do this frequently `save=dict.fromkeys(a,0)` and then call `a=save.copy()` which is faster in some cases(large dicts)